# Failed to connect ip on android Device

Tags: android-studio, retrofit

i tried to run apps on hand phone device and i can't login because the device cant connect the url, but if i run it one emulator on pc it was working properly. i am using retrofit with MySql as database.

[this is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuxWQ.jpg)

i already check the ip config and it's same like my retrofit code.

[code and the ip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbRo2.png)

Help me please.